# SQL custom column from another queried column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the below query which works as I need it, but I also want to add the name of the ParentCategoryID in another column which would need to custom as there is no column for ParentCategory name. The only way I can get that is by referencing the CategoryID that I retrieved from t.ParenCategoryID. CategoryID and ParentCategoryID are in the same table. Can this be accomplished a sub query?

```
SELECT c.ContentID
    ,c.Title
    ,t.CategoryID
    ,t.Name
   ,t.ParentCategoryID
FROM Content c
INNER JOIN ContentCategory g ON c.ContentID = g.ContentID
RIGHT JOIN Category t ON g.CategoryID = t.CategoryID
ORDER BY g.CategoryID
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT c.ContentID
       ,c.Title
       ,t.CategoryID
       ,t.Name
       ,t.ParentCategoryID
       ,tc.Name AS ParentCategoryName
FROM   Content c
       INNER JOIN ContentCategory g 
           ON c.ContentID = g.ContentID
       RIGHT JOIN Category t 
           ON g.CategoryID = t.CategoryID
       LEFT JOIN Category tc 
           ON t.CategoryID = tc.ParentCategoryID
ORDER BY g.CategoryID
```

Comment: It's very confusing to see INNER...RIGHT...LEFT.

Comment: Thanks. The name results for the parent category name are not matching, but I think that's a byproduct of my initial query. I did a similar query using different tables and it worked fine.